# RecyclerView not updated after fetching data from Firestore

Tags: java, android

I don't know why my app is crashing when I was sending data which was coming from Firestore in profile Fragment to followerAdapter. I don't know what the problem in *followerProfileList()*.

FollowerAdapter.java

```
package com.faizanSocialMediaProject.socialmediaapp.adapter;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.faizanSocialMediaProject.socialmediaapp.R;
import com.faizanSocialMediaProject.socialmediaapp.databinding.FriendrvSampleBinding;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class FollowerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FollowerAdapter.viewHolder> {
    private List<String> list;
    private Context context;

    public FollowerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    public void setFollowerList(List<String> list) {
        this.list=list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.friendrv_sample,parent,false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
       String model=list.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(model).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile).into(holder.binding.profileImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list!= null)
            return list.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public  static class  viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        FriendrvSampleBinding binding;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
             binding=FriendrvSampleBinding.bind(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

ProfileFragment.java

```
package com.faizanSocialMediaProject.socialmediaapp.fragments;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.faizanSocialMediaProject.socialmediaapp.R;
import com.faizanSocialMediaProject.socialmediaapp.adapter.FollowerAdapter;
import com.faizanSocialMediaProject.socialmediaapp.model.Follow;
import com.faizanSocialMediaProject.socialmediaapp.model.UserDataModel;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldPath;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.SetOptions;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView coverImage;
    ImageView profile_image;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    TextView userName;
    TextView userProfession;
    UserDataModel currentUser=new UserDataModel();
    FollowerAdapter adapter;
    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //crating instances of auth and storage
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        storage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        //  fetching data of image from fireStoreDatabase
        db.collection("Users").document(auth.getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
              if(task.isSuccessful()){
                  DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                  if (document != null && document.exists()) {
                      // here we are getting data from database and storing it in UserModel object and saving valuing in our textview and setting Images
                   String image_link= document.getString("cover_image");
                   currentUser.setCover_image(image_link);
                   currentUser.setName(document.getString("name"));
                   currentUser.setProfession(document.getString("profession"));

                   currentUser.setProfile_image(document.getString("profile_image"));
                   // setting cover image of user
                      Picasso.get()
                              .load(currentUser.getCover_image()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile).into(coverImage);

                    // setting profile image of user
                      Picasso.get().load(currentUser.getProfile_image()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile).into(profile_image);

                      //setting user name and profession
                      userName.setText(currentUser.getName());
                      userProfession.setText(currentUser.getProfession());

                  }
              }
            }
        });


        // Showing list of friends we have

        ImageView changeCoverImageButton=view.findViewById(R.id.changeCoverImage);
        coverImage=view.findViewById(R.id.coverImage);
        profile_image=view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        //user name and profession
        userName=view.findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        userProfession=view.findViewById(R.id.UserProfession);

        RecyclerView friendRv=view.findViewById(R.id.friendRv);


                FollowerAdapter adapter=new FollowerAdapter(getContext());
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
                friendRv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                friendRv.setAdapter(adapter);
                followerProfileList();

        //changing profile_image os user
        profile_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,13);
            }
        });


        //changing cover Image
        changeCoverImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                // it give us resulting image
                startActivityForResult(intent,11);
            }
        });
        return  view;
    }
    //fetching profile info from database
   public void followerProfileList(){
        db.collection("Users").document(Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getUid())).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
             UserDataModel model= documentSnapshot.toObject(UserDataModel.class);
             List<String> docIds=new ArrayList<>();
                assert model != null;
                for(Follow follower:model.getFollowers()){
                 docIds.add(follower.getFollowedBy());
             }
                db.collection("Users").whereIn(FieldPath.documentId(),docIds).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                      List<String> friends=new ArrayList<>();
                      for(UserDataModel person:queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(UserDataModel.class)){
                          friends.add(person.getProfile_image());
                      }
                      adapter.setFollowerList(friends);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        }
   // using result in the form of Uri from given intent of change cover image
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if(requestCode==11){
           if(data.getData()!=null){
               Uri uri= data.getData();
               coverImage.setImageURI(uri);

               //storing image info in database storage
               StorageReference reference=storage.getReference().child("cover_image").child(auth.getUid());
               reference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
//                       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                               // saving it into database
                               currentUser.setCover_image(uri.toString());
                               db.collection("Users").document(auth.getUid()).set(currentUser,SetOptions.mergeFields("cover_image"));
                           }
                       });
                   }
               });
           }
       }
       else{
           if(data.getData()!=null){
               Uri uri= data.getData();
               profile_image.setImageURI(uri);

               //storing image info in database storage
               StorageReference reference=storage.getReference().child("profile_image").child(auth.getUid());
               reference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
//                       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                               currentUser.setProfile_image(uri.toString());
                               db.collection("Users").document(auth.getUid()).set(currentUser, SetOptions.mergeFields("profile_image"));
                           }
                       });
                   }
               });
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Follow.java

```
package com.faizanSocialMediaProject.socialmediaapp.model;

public class Follow {
   private String followedBy;
   private  long followedAt;

    public Follow() {
    }

    public String getFollowedBy() {
        return followedBy;
    }

    public void setFollowedBy(String followedBy) {
        this.followedBy = followedBy;
    }

    public long getFollowedAt() {
        return followedAt;
    }

    public void setFollowedAt(long followedAt) {
        this.followedAt = followedAt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also post the error in the logcat so we could help.

Comment: are you sure you are getting correct response from firestore? your code looks fine to work successfully

Answer (score 0):

Replace your setFollowerList method with below one,

```
public void setFollowerList(List<String> list) {
   this.list.clear();
   this.list.addAll(list);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Adapter should hold one list reference to refresh it's content.